# Tensorflow how to modify a pre-trained Model saved as checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I trained a FCN model in Tensorflow following implementation in [link](https://github.com/shekkizh/FCN.tensorflow/blob/master/FCN.py) and saved the complete model as checkpoint, Now I want to use the saved model(pre-trained) for different problem.
I tried to restore the model from checkpoint by specifying the weights in **Saver** as:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver({"weights" : [w1_1,w1_2,w2_1,w2_2,w3_1,w3_2,w3_3,w3_4, w4_1, w4_2, w4_3, w4_4,w5_1,w5_2,w5_3,w6,w7]})
```

I am getting weights as:

```
w1_1=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,scope='inference/conv1_1_w')
```

and so on....
I am not able to restore it successfully (up to specific layer).
Tensorflow version:0.12r

Comment: Can you please share the error that you're seeing? As far as I can tell, the type of your first argument to `tf.train.Saver` is not quite right: instead of a dictionary mapping one key to a list of variables, it will expect a dictionary mapping keys to individual variables.

Comment: @mrry you are exactly right, but I am getting individual weights from the list, can you explain your point in details please?

Answer (score 2):

Either you can call `init = tf.initialize_variables([list_of_vars])` followed by `sess.run(init)` and that would reinitialize those variables for you, or you can recreate the graph with same structure from the point where you want to freeze the weights but keep different names for variables. Further in case you only want to train certain variables only, you can pass those variables only to optimizer. `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss,var_list = [wi, wj, ....])`

Comment: Do I need to restore and initialize biases?

Comment: Yes, its not hard to see that they are required by the layers you decide to freeze and reinitialize them if you need to.

Comment: Btw, you reintialize only those variables that you need to train  again, others you can use directly

Comment: This is the problem I am not able to do it... and thats the question how to do it?

Comment: the line w1_1=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,scope='inference/conv1_1_w will only give variables in first conv layer that is by scope, remove scope and you can get all the trainable variables

Comment: my problem is to pass the weights to network how can I do that

Comment: if wi is weight you want to assign value to, do sess.run(wi.assign(some_value))